# Skype web-client stuck displaying (1) in title, indicating new message that does not exist

Tags: skype

*Posted as Q&A after finding a solution.*

### The Problem

Using [web.skype.com](https://web.skype.com/), die client got stuck displaying the title as `(1) Skype` even though there are no new chat notifications. Logging out and back in, clearing cache, etc. all didn't help, and constantly having a new message indicated is distracting.

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

In the web client, when there are new notifications, it is possible to right-click the "Chats" icon. This brings up both the context menu and a "mark all as read" button.

[image]

Using this, I got rid of the `(1) Skype` state.